# Find in runtime the string key corresponding to the text of a TextView

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm making a simple tool in my app to find in runtime the string key corresponding to the text of a TextView. That could be useful to identify a string in your screen and make easier the localization process.
E.g. I have a TextView

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/my_text"
    android:id="@+id/textview1" />
```

This is my string that I want to find

```
<string name="my_text">My Text</string>
```

So programmatically I want to get the key of the previous string maybe using this method `getResources().getResourceEntryName(int idRes)`

or if it's possible searching the text in the string.xml

Comment: What do you mean by "the key of the previous string"? Please explain.

Comment: I mean the string name "my_text". From the TextView object I want to find the correspondent name of the string.

Comment: @br00 Did you find the solution for this ? Is it possible to get the key ?

Answer (score 0):

If you got view containing searched string you can use:
`getResources().getResourceEntryName(foundView.getId())`

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your question, unfortunately you cant do that. The only way would be to use reflection on R.string class to iterate overal all the fields and find the mathing one, but not with the common API.

Comment: is it possibile to access to the R.string file in runtime?